# Simulating data with specified mean, minimum and maximum

Tags: distributions, simulation

I am doing some simulations and the client said that one variable should range from -20 to +65 with a mean of 30. Clearly, it can't be normal, but it should be roughly bell-shaped.

Later, I will have to simulate data with somewhat different mean, min and max.

What are good ways to do this?

I am using SAS but also have access to R.

ADDING DETAIL:  This is the perecentage of epileptic seizures that are not reported by the patient. I'm figuring out how much that affects power in trials.

Comment: What do you need to do with the data? My default for sampling with constraints is usually to use stan (Rstan), since I usually also need to perform some modeling with the samples along the way... For your problem, you can write the program to read the min and limits as data, so you can use the same program again and again.

Comment: In some fields--especially project management and in anything touched by business consultants with an imperfect grasp of statistical modeling--a [triangular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) is routinely used.  As I'm sure you know, the distributional shape should be determined by *what* you are simulating. You might also do your client a favor by including some values outside the range, unless they are physically impossible, because most people are too conservative in their range estimates.

Comment: Could you please clarify how numbers that range from $-20$ to $65$ could be *proportions* of anything?

Comment: Some people miss episodes, some report episodes that didn't happen

Comment: If you have access to matlab, it can be done using simulink toolboxes as far as I know.

Comment: But those numbers are clearly not proportions, which typically would lie in the interval $[-1,1]$.  Are they counts or percents or something else?  In any event it begins to look like the distribution ought to be conditional on the number of seizures rather than a fixed distribution.

Comment: They are percents. Sorry for that.

Comment: Is there any pre-existing data from which you could bootstrap or surmise the general shape of the distribution, or are you flying completely blind?

Comment: No, there is no preexisting data.  I was surprised how little is known about these data.

Comment: 1. Note that *percentage of seizures not reported by the patient* cannot be negative, yet the actual quantity takes negative values, so the statement at the end of the question must be wrong. 2. Is the intent that a *sample* have the specified min, max and mean, or that the *distribution* have the specified min max and mean, even if the min and max might never actually show up in a sample? 3. Is the distribution intended to be discrete (31, 6, -2) or continuous (31.357..., 6.0342...)?

Comment: I admit that I am still foggy about why the value can be negative also, but it has something to do with the possibility of missed episodes and over reported episodes. Secretly I hoped negative values are incorrect so that a well known distribution could be used.

Comment: The value could be negative because (apparently) some people report episodes that did not actually occur.

Comment: Why not ask the client to give you their intuition about (a) the rate of seizures, (b) the rate of seizure reports, and then simulate this latent variable from two Poisson distributions?

Answer (score 3):

Drawing on [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber)'s comment, I propose a [triangle-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) strategy.

The mean of the triangle distribution is:

$E[x] = \frac{a+b+c}{3}$

where $a$ and $b$ are the upper and lower bounds of the range and $c \in [a,b]$ is the mode. That $a=-25$ and $b=60$ implies that $c=55$.

According to the [CRAN page on probability distributions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html):

> Triangle/trapezoidal distribution : packages [`triangle`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/triangle/index.html), [`mc2d`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mc2d/index.html), [`ExtDist`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ExtDist/index.html) and [VGAM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VGAM/index.html) provide `d`, `p`, `q`, `r` functions for the triangle distribution.... A fast random generator is available for the triangle distribution is implemented [*sic*] in [`Runuran`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Runuran/index.html) as well as the density function.

You would, of course, use the applicable `r` function within whichever of these or other packages you decide to use.

As an alternative to the triangle distribution, you might considered the [generalized trapezoidal distribution](http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~dorpjr/Publications/JournalPapers/Metrika2003VanDorp.pdf), but doing so would complicate your choices for the parameter values because there is a parameter for each of the interior vertices of the distribution.